# Writing ArcMap Label Expression in VBscript?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, labeling, vbscript

I have to columns, pipe material and pipe size, I only want to label pipes with a size greater than 2"

I am trying to do this but keeps kicking back and error, can anyone assist in what im doing wrong?

```
Function FindLabel ( [PIPE_MATERIAL] , [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] )
  if ( [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] > 2") then
   FindLabel = [PIPE_MATERIAL] 
  end if
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function FindLabel ( [PIPE_MATL], [PIPE_DIA] )
 ' this just pulls first digit from PIPE_DIA string 2", 3" & converts to Double type - you may have to play around with...  
   If CDbl( Mid([PIPE_DIA], 1, Len([PIPE_DIA])-1)) > 2 then
      FindLabel = [PIPE_MATL]
   else 
      FindLabel = ""
   end if
End Function
```

Adding unit decorations to a data field (like inch marks etc.) is always a BAD idea, poor database structure. The reason your code fails is your mixing data types in your "If" statement. You need to compare either 'all string' or 'all number' types.

Comment: cm1 - great that worked! Thanks alot! PS) The dataset was inherited from someone else I didnt create it.

Comment: Great!  `If CDbl( Mid([PIPE_DIA], 1, Len([PIPE_DIA])-1)) > 2 then` is probably better than `If CDbl(Mid([PIPE_DIA], 1, 1))> 2 then`   I fully understand inheriting 'data badness'... good luck.

Comment: You read my mind, I was just going to respond with it only showing sizes below double figures, but that follow up solved it :) many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be near your 'if ( [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] > 2") then' line.

Your wanting to perform a logical mathematical operation there and the double quote after the 2" is probably getting in the way - getting interpreted as a string.

if PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER is an integer field then you need to do something like:

```
Function FindLabel ( [PIPE_MATL], [P_INT_DIAM] )
if ( [P_INT_DIAM] > 2) then
  FindLabel = [PIPE_MATL]
end if
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, I tried adjusting it to Function FindLabel ( [PIPE_MATERIAL] , [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] )
if ( [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER]  > 2) then
  FindLabel = [PIPE_MATERIAL] 
end if
End Function  but still kicks back an error, the data type is double if that makes a difference

Comment: What's the error message returned when you click the 'Verify' button?

Comment: also it might be worth mentioning to you, that the pipe internal diameter columns actually have that unit value in them " ie inches 6" 4" 8" etc, is that gonna confuse things or is it still viable?

Comment: The expression contains an error. Modify the expression and try again. Error 13 on line 2. Type mismatch: esri__1'.

Comment: Try using single quotes: if ( [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] > '2"' ) then

Comment: Function FindLabel ( [PIPE_MATERIAL]  , [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER]  )
 If ( [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] > ' 2" ' ) Then
 FindLabel = [PIPE_MATERIAL] 
 End If
End Function ---Kicks back 'the expression contains an error. Modify the expresion and try again' .... really frustrating because it seems like a simple straight forward expression, no idea why it isnt working

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really good with VB, so I'll offer a Python attempt. You would need to change from the Visual Basic parser to the Python parser and give something like this a try:

```
def FindLabel ( [PIPE_MATL], [PIPE_DIA] ):
  # assign pipe diameter string to S
  S = [PIPE_DIA]
  # trim the double-quote character from the end of the diam string/chg to float variable
  if (float(S[:-1]) > 2.0):
    return [PIPE_MATL]
  else:
    return ''
```

Be sure to keep the indentations intact if you cut-&-paste this. Whitespace/indentation is important/means 'run this block of code together' to Python.

Comment: Im running 10.0 the only parser options I have is Jscript & vb :(